# sent post request @action to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, razor

I want to send POST request to AdminController. But when i watch it in debugger, the request is GET.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="button" formmethod="post" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index","Admin",new {rowID = @p.ProductID})'" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It is the Controller that determines the verb, not the html form. Decorate your controller action with `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wrote code to do a GET request on the submit button click !

> onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index","Admin",new {rowID =
>   @p.ProductID})'"

Here you are setting the location.href value to the `/Admin/Index` and it will be a new GET request.

If you want to post, simply remove the `onclick` event on the button. If you want to send the ProductID value, you can keep that in a hidden input field inside your form and when you click submit the value of this form element will be also submitted.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Admin"))
{
  <input type="hidden" name="rowID" value="@p.ProductID" />
  <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
}
```

Assuming your HttpPost Index action method of AdminController has a parameter with same name as the input name to accept the productId.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int rowID)
{
  // to do : Return something
}
```